# JSON.Parse SyntaxError only during GET request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

As the title says. I get a SyntaxError out of JSON.parse(), but it only happens when I make a GET request at an inopportune time.

I'm running a local web server using node.js. I have some data being pushed to a different local socket and the callback function in a .js file parses it before doing some processing and storing it in a local array. This whole chain works perfectly fine, but if I refresh the page at the wrong time, the JSON.parse() function throws a SyntaxError. My current workaround is just to use a try-catch statement and dump the data if it fails.

I did try to just recursively parse the data until it succeeds, but that caused a stack error, which got me really confused. When I print the data it's trying to parse, it's exactly the same as all the data it's been parsing.

Any ideas? I've been stuck on this for a couple of days.

Comment: What are the response headers for the response?

Comment: Could you post the JSON code? Perhaps your file doesn't have the right syntax. You could try pasting it [here](http://jsonlint.com/) which checks if it's in the correct format.

Comment: Post your code where you are parsing and json as well so that we can see